# How to put separators in large data set?

Tags: plotting, dataset

I have a large data set. Here is a part of it:

```
{1., 18.6, 460.4346}
{2., 28.4, 460.4346}
{3., 38.2, 460.4346}
{4., 48., 460.4346}
```

How to put a comma separator using mathematica command between the curly brackets so that it converts to table as follows:
`{{1., -28.6, 46.4346},{2., -28.4, 46.4346},{3., -28.2, 46.4346},{4., -28., 46.4346}}`.

Here I put the commas by hand. Thanks

Comment: no, its the output of For[Print.....]

Comment: the problem is that its too long and takes many hours to run. Even I provide the source, still need tailoring the data.

Comment: If you are stuck with the output of `For[Print ....]` just cut the text out of the notebook, paste it into a text editor, edit it, then cut'n'paste back. ?

Comment: Its more than 2000 lines, hard to edit it in the editor.

Comment: I copied to the editor and then imported. It now inserts commas, but now the data output in the form, "{1., 18.6, 460.4346}"
"{2., 28.4, "460.4346"}"
"{3., 38.2, "460.4346"}"
"{4., 48., "460.4346"}"

Comment: Can you edit the notebook directly? The one where all of the Prints are?

Comment: If you can edit the notebook, one thing you could do is redefine what Print does. You could redefine Print to, for example, Sow the data. Then wrap the For with Reap. The result should be an actual List at that point which you can manipulate as you normally would. If this seems like a feasible option, I (or anyone here) can show you how.

Comment: If you are using `For[..., Print[...]]` to generate the dataset, you are not actually generating a dataset - you are merely printing its elements one by one. Look at `Table` to actually collect the results into a list. In the unlikely case that doesn't work for you (e.g. due to some strange iteration specification), look at `Reap`/`Sow`

Comment: @LukasLang: Can you please apply your method on the example here in the answers. One thing is certain that I cannot run the program again since takes a week. Certainly, I used For[..., Print[...]] to get the data.

Answer (score 2):

Copy paste data and save as txt file.

```
dnc = ReadList["C:/data_no_commas.txt"]
Map[Head, dnc, {2}]
Map[Head, dnc, {1}]
```

[image]

I agree with other comments that this should be natively generated.

Comment: I don't understand any purpose of this answer. All numbers are already real.

Comment: This answer is an improvement over: `I copied to the editor and then imported. It now inserts commas, but now the data output in the form, "{1., 18.6, 460.4346}" "{2., 28.4, "460.4346"}" "{3., 38.2, "460.4346"}" "{4., 48., "460.4346"}"`

Comment: I am already getting this, there is nothing new here. Do you know how to remove "..." from the curly brackets?

Comment: You can start a new question about it.

Comment: Look my comment above, I have already got this step before you suggested. If know the solution, please edit your answer.